# Nginx - nginx: [emerg] unexpected ","

Tags: nginx

My nginx web server has this config for sites-enabled:

```
server {

        root /var/www/portfolio/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mytest123.digital;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /savings {
                alias /var/www/savings/build;
                index index.html index.html index.nginx-debian.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


        location /v3/api/ {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/mytest123/mytest123.sock;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 500s;
        }

        location /v4/api/ {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/mytest123/mytest123.sock;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 500s;
        }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mytest123.digital/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mytest123.digital/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = mytest123.digital) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mytest123.digital;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But when I try to check syntax with `sudo nginx -t` it gives me the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-115:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "," in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/portfolio.save:25
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What is wrong with my config, please?

Comment: are you sure?  that file  is  incorrect,there may be error for other conf file because it checks all conf files

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that a new config file has been created during my process of editing the original config file. The newly created config file was called new_config_file.save and this caused the issue since it contained not correct configuration. The config file itself (from which I posted the configuration in the question) contained correct configuration.

Comment: The file name with the problem is right there in the error msg.